# Is there a faster method than nested iterrows?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am creating pairs of rows from a pandas dataframe to make some calculation based on each pairs and create a new dataframe.

```
affinity = []
for prod1 in data3.iterrows():
        for prod2 in data3.iterrows():
           if prod1[0] != prod2[0]:
               pair = pd.concat([prod1[1],prod2[1]], axis=1)
               total = max(np.count_nonzero(pair, axis=0))
               match = pair[(pair.iloc[:, 0]==1) & (pair.iloc[:, 1]==1)]
               prob = match.shape[0] / total
               dat = [prod1[0],prod2[0],prob]
               affinity.append(dat)
affinity = pd.DataFrame(affinity)
```

Is there a faster way to do the equivalent? I have to check every pairs possible except the row with itself. I know there is itertools.product but I don't know how to use it with rows of a pandas dataframe. I saw some use case with lists only.

Input sample:

```
       ticket1  ticket2  ticket3
class1      0         0        0
class2      0         1        0
class3      0         1        0
```

expected output:

```
  col1   col2  col3
class1  class2  0.0
class2  class3  1.0
class3  class1  0.0
```

Comment: please provide example input data and the matching expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite similar to a covariance calculation! Let's do it step by step with numpy:

**Warning I'm assuming you have only 0s and 1s in your array because you check equalities vs 1 and 0**

```py
data = data3.to_numpy()

match_matrix = data @ data.T 
# Matix multiplication : 
# match[i,j] = data[i][0]*data[j][0] + data[i][0]*data[j][0] + data[i][0]*data[j][0]

total_per_row = np.count_nonzero(data,axis=1) # can be replaced with sum

total_matrix = np.maximum(total_per_row[:,np.newaxis],total_per_row[np.newaxis,:])
# Broadcast and compare maximums:
# total_matrix[i,j] = max(total_per_row[i],total_per_row[j])


probability_matrix = match_matrix / total_matrix
```

You now have `affinity` in matrix form! You can load it back to a dataframe and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) them to look like your desired output or keep them as is and display some correlation matrixes.

Edit: Adding how to get exactly the expected result:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(
        np.triu(np.ones(probability_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(bool),
        np.nan_to_num(probability_matrix),
        np.nan,
    ),
    index=data3.index,
    columns=data3.index,
).stack().reset_index()
```